# .htaccess rewrite rule ,last query string is append to the url

Tags: .htaccess, content-management-system, directoryindex

Hi i make one cms sites and i need to rewrite my url

current my url is http://www.example.com/index.php?link=pages&cmsid=2&cmsLink=Carpet
it refers the *cmsLink*
I want my url like http://www.example.com/Carpet
I am using the following code

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options +Indexes
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index.php?link=(.*)&cmsid=(.*)&cmsLink=(.*) $3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achive this url it not directly possible with .htaccess
I use regular expression and other tings in htacess as well

I put remove the cmsid

current my url is http://www.example.com/index.php?link=pages&cmsLink=Carpet

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/admin
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(.*).php
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?link=pages&cmsLink=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

it return me http://www.example.com/Carpet

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your last rule to this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php?link=pages&cmsid=2&cmsLink=$1
```

Since you want to have url like http://www.example.com/Carpet, so `cmsid` and `link` in your url has to be hardcoded to `2` and `pages`.

Comment: cmsid and link is not hardcoded  i tried it like `RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)\$ /index.php?link=$1&cmsid=$2&cmsLink=$3 [L]` and it give me out put like **http://www.example.com/pages/2/Carpet** but i want the url like **http://www.example.com/Carpet**

Comment: If you want url like example.com/Carpet then how will .htaccess know about the value 2? From where will .htaccess get the value 2? Or is the value 2 always remain same for urls like example.com/Table?

Comment: URL rewrite uses values from the incoming user request and redirects it into some other URL. So all the values required should be part of the original request. So if `2` is not in your original request (that is example.com/Carpet) then you cannot pass `2` in the redirected url (index.php?cmsid=2&cmsLink=Carpet).

Comment: Yes Aziz you are right that why i change in my php code and pass the unique cmsLink and remove the cmsid from the query string,and write .htaccess